# Method Reference. Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method

Tags: java-8, method-reference

Can someone explain to me, 
why passing a non-static method-reference to method `File::isHidden` is ok, 
but passing  method reference to a non-static method `MyCass::mymethod` - gives me a 
**"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method"** ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File[] files = new File("C:").listFiles(File::isHidden); // OK
    test(MyCass::mymethod); // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
}

static interface FunctionalInterface{
    boolean function(String file);
}

class MyCass{
    boolean mymethod(String input){
        return true;
    }
}

// HELPER
public static void test(FunctionalInterface functionalInterface){}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Method references to non-static methods require an instance to operate on.**

In the case of the `listFiles` method, the argument is a `FileFilter` with `accept(File file)`. As you operate on an instance (the argument), you can refer to its instance methods:

```
listFiles(File::isHidden)
```

which is shorthand for

```
listFiles(f -> f.isHidden())
```

Now why can't you use `test(MyCass::mymethod)`? Because you simply don't have an instance of `MyCass` to operate on.

You can however create an instance, and then pass a method reference to your instance method:

```
MyCass myCass = new MyCass(); // the instance
test(myCass::mymethod); // pass a non-static method reference
```

or

```
test(new MyCass()::mymethod);
```

Edit: `MyCass` would need to be declared static (`static class MyCass`) in order to be accessible from the main method.

Comment: You cannot instantiate `MyClass` from within a `static` method (such as `main`) because is is a _non-static_ inner class. You would have to declare the class as static. I am assuming the code in the original example is wrapped inside a class.

Comment: @Peter As per the documentation, Method References is absolutely not a static call. It works on both static and non- static methods. If going by your explanation then who exactly creates the instance in the case of String class private Function<String, String> f1 = String::toUpperCase;

Answer (score 1):

As peter-walser pointed out, since `MyCass::mymethod` is an instance method it requires an instance to be converted to a `Function` instance.

The `static` in front of your interface declaration just makes it a *static interface*, it does not turn each method into a static one.

A possible solution would be to declare the method inside the class as static:

```
class MyCass{
   static boolean mymethod(String input){
       return true;
   }
}
```

To understand better how it works, you can consider the code equivalente to the method reference `MyCass::mymethod` that is (assuming the above modified declaration of `MyClass`):

```
new FunctionalInterface{
  boolean function(String file){
    return MyClass.mymethod(file);
  }
}
```

Your original code would attempt to sort-of translate into:

```
new FunctionalInterface{
  boolean function(String file){
    return _missing_object_.mymethod(); # mymethod is not static
  }
}
```

Another possibility is using a [`BiFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html)
instead of your `FunctionalInterface`. In that case the first argument of `apply` would be the object and the second would be the argument to `mymethod`.

Comment: Your first example has to be `MyClass.mymethod(file)`. The OP's code would also be translated into that. That's where the "Cannot make a static reference ..." error comes from. There is no static reference in your second example.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

You're trying to access a static method through the class.

```
test(MyCass::mymethod); // Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method
```

Is the same as

```
test(v -> MyCass.mymethod(v)); // static access
```

**Solution**

Make the method static

```
class MyCass {
  static boolean mymethod(String input) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Or use an object as reference

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyCass myCass = new MyCass();
  test(myCass::mymethod);
}
```

Comment: Incase of String class, even though toUppercase is non-static then why this does not give error Function<String, String> f1 = String::toUpperCase;